# How to fix 'Class doi does not exist error in Laravel when generating pdf in mpdf?

Tags: laravel, mpdf

I want to generate pdf using mpdf but unfortunately there's an error that came up:

> 'Class doesn't exist'.

When I'm posting data using post method like this:
`{{ $app->dt_arrive }}. {{ $app->day_arrive }}, {{ $app->year_arrive }}`

I've tried generating it in a different blade view but the error still comes up.

I want to post this in my pdf:

```
<tr>
   <td style="padding: 5px 10px;padding-top: 5px;border: solid 1px #000;padding-top: 7px;font-size: 14px;color: #646363;">Date</td>
   <td style="font-weight:bolder;padding: 5px 10px;padding-top: 5px;border: solid 1px #000;padding-top: 7px;font-size: 14px;text-transform:uppercase;">{{ date('M. j, Y', strtotime($app->doi)) }}</td>
</tr>
```

I created in my controllers codes for generating pdf:

```
function generate_pdf() {
    $data = [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('registration.visa-register#paymentinfo', $data);
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
}
```

and in my routes.

```
Route::get('/getPDF', 'RegistrationController@generate_pdf');
```

I'm expecting to generate pdf file using mpdf.

Comment: What laravel package are you using for mpdf?

Comment: I'm using niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf package

Comment: Can you dd() your $app variable, and paste it in your initial question?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views.)

It explains in detail how to properly pass data to your view.

With $app->doi you are trying to access doi class instance which does not exists and it throws an error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir but I want to create a pdf view so I declare this on my controller

Comment: function generate_pdf() {
    $data = [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('registration.visa-register#paymentinfo', $data);
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');